# Fargate tasks not calling aws services without aws configure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am unable to call aws services from fargate tasks - secrets manager and sns.

I want these services to be invoked from inside the docker image which is hosted on ECR. When I run the pipeline everything loads and run correctly except when the script inside the docker container is invoked, it throws an error. The script makes a call to either secrets manager or sns. The error thrown is -

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

If I do aws configure then the error goes away and every things works smoothly. But I do not want to store the aws credentials anywhere.

When I open task definitions I can see two roles - `pipeline-task` and `ecsTaskExecutionRole`

[image]
[image]

Although, I have given full administrator rights to both of these roles, the pipeline still throws error. Is there any place missing where I can assign roles/policies etc. I want to completely avoid using aws configure.

Comment: Can you show one of the commands you are running, that is resulting in that error? If you are using the AWS CLI tool, it should be picking up the `pipeline-task-role` IAM role.

Comment: `aws sns publish --topic-arn $TOPIC_ARN --message "Hello message"`
It is invoked from a shell script which is present inside the docker container. Yes, I am using AWS CLI.

Comment: The problem I think however is that because the pipeline is invoked from gitlab, the environment variable required must be placed within the gitlab's interface. This is what I am trying to achieve -
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/

Answer (score 0):

If the script with the issue is not a PID 1 process ( used to stop and start the container ), it will not automatically read the Task Role (pipeline-task-role). From your description, this sounds like the case.

Add this to your Dockerfile:

RUN echo 'export $(strings /proc/1/environ | grep AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI)' >> /root/.profile

The AWS SDK from the script should know where to pick up the credentials from after that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my problem was the same as yours but I also experienced this kind of problem where I had been set the task role but the container don't get the right permissions. After spending a few days, I discovered that if you set any of the AWS environment variables

- **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID**
- **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY**
- or **AWS_DEFAULT_REGION**

into the task definition, the "Credential provider chain" will stop at the "Static credentials" step, so the SDK your script is using will look for the other credentials within the .aws/.credentials file and as it can't find them it throws `Unable to locate credentials`.

If you want to know further about the Credential provider chain you could read about it in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/standardized-credentials.html